# How to count connected cells in a grid?

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm trying to solve the Hackerrank problem ["Connected Cells in a Grid"](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/connected-cell-in-a-grid). The task is to find the largest region (connected cells consisting of ones) in the grid.

My approach was to add the number of ones I find only if the element hasn't been visited yet, then I take the maximum of several paths. It doesn't seem to be working for the following test case:

```
5
5
1 1 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 1 1
```

Is there something wrong with my approach?

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 10
bool visited[MAX][MAX];

int maxRegion(vector<vector<int>> const& mat, int i, int j) { 
  int result;

  if ((i == 0 && j == 0) || visited[i][j]) {
    result = 0;
  }
  else if (i == 0) {
      result = mat[i][j-1] + maxRegion(mat, i, j-1);
  }
  else if (j == 0) {
      result = mat[i-1][j] + maxRegion(mat, i-1, j);
  }
  else {
    result = mat[i-1][j-1] +
      max({maxRegion(mat, i-1, j),
           maxRegion(mat, i, j-1),
           maxRegion(mat, i-1, j-1)});
  }
  visited[i][j] = true;
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's very natural to formulate this program as a [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) problem. Specifically, I've used [`boost::graph`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/graph/example/connected_components.cpp) for this.

The idea is to build a graph whose each entry in the matrix is a node, and there are edges between horizontal and vertical 1 entries. Once such a graph is built, all that is needed is to run the connected components algorithm, and find the biggest component.

The following code does so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/connected_components.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main()
{   
    vector<vector<int>> v{{1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 1}};

    typedef adjacency_list <vecS, vecS, undirectedS> graph;

    graph g(v.size() * v.size());

    // Populate the graph edges
    for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; ++i)
        for(size_t j = 0; j < v[i].size() - 1; ++j)
        {
            if(v[i][j] == 1 && v[i + 1][j] == 1)
                add_edge(i * v.size() + j, (i + 1) * v.size() + j, g);
            else if(v[i][j] == 1 && v[i][j + 1] == 1)
                add_edge(i * v.size() + j, i * v.size() + j + 1, g);
        }

     // Run the connected-components algorithm.
     vector<int> component(num_vertices(g));
     int num = connected_components(g, &component[0]);

     // Print out the results.
     std::vector<int>::size_type i;
     for(i = 0; i != component.size(); ++i)
         cout << "Vertex (" << i / v.size() << ", " << i % v.size()  << ") is in component " << component[i] << endl;
     cout << endl;
}
```

The output is

```
Vertex (0, 0) is in component 0
Vertex (0, 1) is in component 0
Vertex (0, 2) is in component 1
Vertex (0, 3) is in component 2
Vertex (0, 4) is in component 3
Vertex (1, 0) is in component 4
Vertex (1, 1) is in component 0
Vertex (1, 2) is in component 0
Vertex (1, 3) is in component 5
Vertex (1, 4) is in component 6
Vertex (2, 0) is in component 7
Vertex (2, 1) is in component 8
Vertex (2, 2) is in component 0
Vertex (2, 3) is in component 9
Vertex (2, 4) is in component 10
Vertex (3, 0) is in component 11
Vertex (3, 1) is in component 12
Vertex (3, 2) is in component 13
Vertex (3, 3) is in component 14
Vertex (3, 4) is in component 15
Vertex (4, 0) is in component 16
Vertex (4, 1) is in component 17
Vertex (4, 2) is in component 18
Vertex (4, 3) is in component 19
Vertex (4, 4) is in component 20
```

Note that the program encodes *i, j* (for the case where the dimension is 5) by *5 i + j*. This is easily invertible.

Answer (score 0):

You can represent the matrix as an undirected graph and use [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) to find the [connected component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) with the most nodes: every cell containing `1` can become a *node*, and there is an *edge* between two nodes if the corresponding cells are adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

If you still need some guidance with the solution, [here is mine in Python](https://github.com/kohn1001/hackerrank/blob/master/python/connected_cell_in_grid.py) - passed all tests :) (visit my [github](https://github.com/kohn1001/hackerrank) to see other challenges that I've solved there in C++ as well)

```
def getBiggestRegion(grid, n, m):
    max_region = 0
    region_size = 0
    for i in xrange(n):
        for j in xrange(m):
            if grid[i][j] == 1:
                region_size = mark_region(grid, i, j, n, m)
                #region_size += 1
                if region_size > max_region:
                    max_region = region_size
    return max_region


def push_if_valid(stack, i, j, n, m):
    if 0 <= i < n and 0 <= j < m:
        stack.append((i, j))

dirs = [[1,0], [0,1], [-1,0], [0,-1], [-1,-1], [-1, 1], [1,1], [1, -1]]
def mark_region(grid, i, j, n, m):
    stack = []
    stack.append((i, j))
    region_size = 0
    while stack:
        curr = stack.pop()
        ci = curr[0]
        cj = curr[1]
        if grid[ci][cj] == 1:
            grid[ci][cj] = 2
            region_size += 1
            #this for loop is for going in all the directions 
            #North, South, East, West, NW, SW, SE, NE
            #in my C++ Pacman sol, I have the actual lines instead
            for dir in dirs:
                push_if_valid(stack, ci + dir[0], cj + dir[1], n, m)

    return region_size

n = int(raw_input().strip())
m = int(raw_input().strip())
grid = []
for grid_i in xrange(n):
    grid_t = list(map(int, raw_input().strip().split(' ')))
    grid.append(grid_t)
print(getBiggestRegion(grid, n, m))
```