# Find the max number of colors in grid

Tags: python, algorithm

I found one python example problem that sounds like "Find the max number of connected colors in the grid". In other words, I have to find the color that is most frequent and also connected together. In my example, it would be **0**, 4 times repeated. I made a grid that looks something like this. Each color is a number.

```
arr = [[0,0,0,1],
       [1,0,2,1],
       [0,2,1,0]]
```

I don't understand what to do next. I think that I have to start iterating through the array `for i in arr:`but what do I have to do next?

Comment: Is this a *graph coloring* problem? Although there exist some (more) efficient algorithms, the problem is quite hard, and thus perhaps you first can try a *branch-and-bound* approach.

Comment: Hint: Read about floodfill

Comment: I would suggest using the flood-fill algorithm. Brute force: Iterate through all indicies, and if it has not yet been filled, start to fill that given index and connected with floodfill while counting the number that have been filled. When done filling, if you filled more than that index has seen before, update a the max connected value for the given index

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count connected cells in a grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562365/how-to-count-connected-cells-in-a-grid)

Comment: @MattTimmermans: not really. That question showed at least some effort.

Comment: I would honestly just try to use networkx or a graph module: there are pre-built algorithms to do this

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a [floodfill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill). This is a brute force solution, and definitely has the possibility of improvement. See comments in code below:

```
#do the floodfill and count number of fills
def floodfill_count(a, i, x, y, tot=0):
    if a[x][y] == i:
        a[x][y] = -1
        tot += 1
        #recursively invoke flood fill on all surrounding cells:
        if x > 0:
            tot = floodfill_count(a, i, x-1, y, tot)
        if x < len(a) - 1:
            tot = floodfill_count(a, i, x+1, y, tot)
        if y > 0:
            tot = floodfill_count(a, i, x, y-1, tot)
        if y < len(a[x]) - 1:
            tot = floodfill_count(a, i, x, y+1, tot)

    return tot

def max_color(arr):
    maxes = {}

    for x in range(len(arr)):
        for y in range(len(arr[x])):
            #color we are looking for
            query_num = arr[x][y]
            #has not been filled yet
            if query_num != -1:
                if query_num in maxes:
                    maxes[query_num] = max(maxes[query_num], floodfill_count(arr, query_num, x, y))
                else:
                    maxes[query_num] = floodfill_count(arr, query_num, x, y)
    #return key associated to max value
    return max(maxes, key=maxes.get)



arr = [[3,3,3,1],
       [1,0,2,1],
       [0,2,1,0]]

max_color = max_color(arr)
print ("max color: " + str(max_color))
```

This works by counting the number of fills on each color that has not been filled, and saving the max value for the given color. The code is a bit of overkill in terms of storing the maxes of all color values, but this way it is expandable for your desired application (second greatest color, etc). I think you have the capability to simplify to just store the max color and max value if you needed to.

Comment: I wonder if this can be improved. It seems like `floodfill_count` is called 43 times in this small example. Adding another row of 4 pushes it up to 58.

Comment: I'm not sure it can on a complexity level. It can improve in small cases here and there, but I think from a complexity standpoint it is required that something to the factor of `n` where `n` is the number of connected color sets is required